# What is the reason for inconsistent behavior of sql query in shell script?

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, sqlplus, ksh

I have a shell script which queries the database and returns the count. Below is the code. Query returns wrong result. But when I run in some sql clients(SQL Tools and SQL Developer) result is as expected.What actually is the reason for inconsistent behavior of same query within shell script?  Expected result is zero but value returned in shell script is 4. Which should be the result of `select count(*) FROM schema1.emp WHERE batch_num in ('1000' ,'1001','1002')`. Somehow second part of where condition is missing when I run through shell script.

```
#!/bin/ksh
run_query() {
    (
        "$SQLPLUS" -SILENT /NOLOG @/dev/stdin <<EndOfSQL
                WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
                WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE

                CONNECT $USER/$PWD@$MY_SID
                SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF;
                SET TERMOUT OFF
                SET TRIMSPOOL ON
                SET PAGESIZE 0
                SET LINESIZE 32767
                SET FEEDBACK OFF
                SET VERIFY OFF
                SET TAB OFF
                SPOOL /dev/stderr
                $1
                SPOOL OFF
EndOfSQL
    ) 3<&1 1<&2 2<&3 3<&-
}

rec_count=$(run_query " select count(*) FROM schema1.emp WHERE batch_num in ('1000' ,'1001','1002') AND stat NOT IN ('NEW','DUPLICATE');")



echo $rec_count
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second query can only yield zero rows.

Comment: Your two queries are different. Your second query should return 0 rows as the `batch_num` can't be 1000 _and_ 1001 _and_ 1002 simultaneously. It can only have 1 value.

Comment: Oh sorry for being so dumb, what a silly mistake I did. Thank you. But can you please tell me if some thing is wrong with 1st query?

Comment: You don't actually say what results the shell script gives you, vs what you get when you run the sql statements in Toad/SQL Developer. It would be helpful if you could add that information to your question.

Comment: Sorry again, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) 
FROM schema1.emp 
WHERE batch_num in ('1000' ,'1001','1002') stat NOT IN ('NEW','DUPLICATE');
```

The first query is **syntactically incorrect** and won't execute at all. There is a `AND` keyword missing before `stat`.

```
select count(*) 
FROM schema1.emp 
WHERE batch_num = '1000' 
AND batch_num = '1001' 
AND batch_num = '1002' 
AND stat <> 'NEW' 
AND stat <> 'DUPLICATE' ;
```

The second query will **always return zero rows**. How can the condition `batch_num = '1000' AND batch_num = '1001' AND batch_num = '1002'` would ever be true? It would work only if it was **IN**, or expand it using **OR** conditions.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry as it was a mistake while writing the question but the actual query has the AND. and the problem with second query , I understood.